# Dynamically Generate JComponent during runtime

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, runtime, jcomponent

got anyways to dynamically generate JComponent like JTextField, JCombobox? What i try is work.., but can only add-on once which's declare as global variable. Got anyway likes changing variable Name during every runtime?

Comment: That question makes no sense to me.  What do dynamically generated components have to do with 'changing a variable name'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't assign a uniques name to every component you dynamically generate.

As you define the text fields you need to add them to a List (or some other data structure). Then you can access the textfields individually from the List.

```
List<JTextField> textFields = new ArrayList<JTextField>();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    JTextField textField = new JTextField();
    textFields.add( textField );
    somePanel.add( textField );
}

somePanel.revalidate();
```

Comment: hmm.i tried this way before...but result still the same..can only add on one textfield,jcombobo,checkbox once a time..hmm not necessary unique just need to dynamically generate.

Comment: Well, your code is wrong. Post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I'd put this code in a method and call it from parent frame with a `pack()` in case new generated components positions are outside the visible area

Comment: You've been given example code. You where asked 2 days ago to post your SSCCE that demonstrates the problem.